# How long does Google App Engine HRD migration take?

Tags: google-app-engine, migration

I have a Master/Slave app that I need to migrate to HRD. The documentation doesn't specify the duration of the process. How long does it take? I know it depends on the data but what I'm trying to ask is, whether this is a synchronous process or I have to enqueue it and it notifies me when it starts/stops? Also, it seems you cannot do it without having downtime, is this correct? Thanks

Comment: It doesn't just depend on the data. It depends on HOW your data is, what indexes you have.... it's SO dependent on a number of things, it can run between minutes, to hours, to days.  This is not a sync process, you start it and it finishes without notifying you (you need to check the console to know when it's done). And YES there will be downtme

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I can't vote it up since you commented instead of creating an answer :(
And YES, there is downtime.

Comment: not a problem, happy to have helped! I don't do this for rep, happy to answer :)

Comment: Did your migration go smoothly at least?

Comment: yep, it was a breeze, thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Patrice said, there IS downtime.